# How to set "Never ask again" for permission before running UI test case

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-espresso, android-testing

Before running UI test I need to set precondition that a user recently choose "Never ask again" for certain permission. Could some one tell me is it even possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use alert box and a flag;
if flag is true then continue
otherwise exit from the program